# Netbeans doesn't deploy on apache webapps directory

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, netbeans, web-applications, deployment

I have a little issue. I have a Maven project, when i run it, work well, but if I see into webapps directory there is no one. I noticed that the webapp is located into "target" folder, in my project directory. Now i want to see my webapps into webapps tomcat's folder. How can i do it?

I'm running:
Ubuntu 16.04
Apache Tomcat 8.0.33
Netbeans 8.1

Thank you to all for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, But if you want a war file for deployment in standalone application server, then right click and selcet **"clean and build"**

Comment: Thank you for answer, but with clean and build my webapps are deployed into folder project_name/target. I need to deploy them into tomcat/webapps folder.

Comment: Any webapp by default run on server, have you installed bundled tomcat,  which comes with netbeans installer?

Comment: No I've installed tomcat alone no with Netbeans. After I've configured it on Netbeans. When I run my webapp work well, but are not deployed into tomcat folder.